# netplan default routes confusion

Tags: netplan

I am new to Netplan... I thought I had everything working ok and on the surface it seems to be, however I am setting up microk8s and getting some weird results on the load balancer and someone somewhere mentioned routing issues, so I looked at my default route and I don't understand.
My netplan is:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: networkd
  ethernets:
    eth0: #Edit this line according to your network interface name.
      dhcp4: false
      addresses:
        - 10.0.0.203/24
      routes:
        - to: default
          via: 10.0.0.1
      nameservers:
        search: [phoenix.local]
        addresses: [10.0.0.253]
```

I am not using dhcp one interface it is static I am using a local dns server for connecting to other nodes on my local net.

But when I do an ip route I see

```
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto static 
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto dhcp src 10.0.0.151 metric 100
```

what is the second default route? is that possibly causing me problems and if so how do I get rid of it?  Sorry, I am kind of old school and haven't worked with linux for a while so trying to catch up with netplan.  thanks

as requested:

/run/systemd/networks/10-netplan-eth0.network contains

```
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Link]
RequiredForOnline=no

[Network]
DHCP=ipv4
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=10.0.0.202/24
DNS=10.0.0.253
Domains=phoenix.local

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=10.0.0.1

[DHCP]
RouteMetric=100
UseMTU=true
```

Bill

Comment: netplan generates the files for your "renderer" in `/run` check in `/run/systemd/networkd` what was generated. Best update your question with the information found. See https://netplan.io/

Answer (score 2):

I feel a little silly, but slightly miffed as well ;-). My /etc/netplan folder had a file in it called 50-cloud-init.yaml containing:

```
# This file is generated from information provided by the datasource.  Changes
# to it will not persist across an instance reboot.  To disable cloud-init's
# network configuration capabilities, write a file
# /etc/cloud/cloud.cfg.d/99-disable-network-config.cfg with the following:
# network: {config: disabled}
network:
    ethernets:
        eth0:
            dhcp4: true
            optional: true
    version: 2
```

So I did what it said and created the 99-disable-network-config.cfg.  I thought that was all there was to it.  Seeing as it said it was automatically generated and would persist through reboots and as I had configured to disable cloud-init, I thought it wouldn't matter if I left it there.  Apparently this is not the case.  This morning on a whim, I moved the file out of that directory and now ip route reports what I would expect:

```
root@uk8s02:/etc/netplan# ip route
default via 10.0.0.1 dev eth0 proto static 
10.0.0.0/24 dev eth0 proto kernel scope link src 10.0.0.202 
blackhole 10.1.125.128/26 proto 80
```

It would seem to me that perhaps text in 50-cloud-init.yaml might also mention to remove the file if disabling cloud-init?  Or so it would seem to me. (or maybe my disable file isn't completely working? but then again I moved the 50-could-init.yaml out and it didn't get regenerated.)

/etc/run/network/10-netplan-eth0.network now contains

```
root@uk8s02:/run/systemd/network# cat 10-netplan-eth0.network 
[Match]
Name=eth0

[Network]
LinkLocalAddressing=ipv6
Address=10.0.0.202/24
DNS=10.0.0.253
Domains=phoenix.local

[Route]
Destination=0.0.0.0/0
Gateway=10.0.0.1
```

which also looks correct.

Thank you for pointing me to that folder Marco!

Bill